# Err import react-native-audio + react-native-sound?

Tags: react-native

I create new project and import react-native-audio and react-native-sound.
Now I'm stuck at error while running it on Android! (Although I run AudioExample working ^^)
I attached file image! (I did npm install 2 packages and react-native link both 2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYhtQ.png)

Comment: You can try https://github.com/luminos-software/react-native-play-sound.

Answer (score 1):

You have to comment out this @Override line in the node_modules/react-native-audio/.../ReactNativeAudioPackage.java. I had this issue and this worked for me.

```
//@Override
```